# Conversion from water pump to air compressor

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I have this graph about a water pump. Unfortunately this is the only information that I have about it:

[image: Graph]

Hypothetically, is there any way to estimate the performance that this pump would have as an air compressor (just roughly), or more information is needed?

I'm assuming that I would be able to control the motor torque to keep the RPMs in the same range.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure this pump will even work with air? Many pumps that pump water will not pump air.

Comment: I'm not sure that it would pump air, it's just hypothetical, assuming that I can control the torque of the motor to compensate the lower viscosity of air. I'm just trying to find an equivalence between water and air through the same pump (if that's even possible).

Comment: Depending on the pump, it's efficacy with air can be the same as water or zero, so it's hard to say based on a single graph alone. To me that looks like a centrifugal pump which generally won't work with air, so it's difficult to say how it would work if it could work. The problem is that centrifugal pumps work by sort-of throwing the water, and then the head is basically the kinetic energy of the water. Since the mass of the air is so low, there really isn't a good mapping between the two since the physics is so different.